# Why are my Ruby methods returning the same thing?

Tags: ruby

The question is related to [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code):

```
# Build a function, `morse_encode(str)` that takes in a string (no
# numbers or punctuation) and outputs the morse code for it. See
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code. Put two spaces between
# words and one space between letters.
#
# You'll have to type in morse code: I'd use a hash to map letters to
# codes. Don't worry about numbers.
#
# I wrote a helper method `morse_encode_word(word)` that handled a
# single word.
#
# Difficulty: 2/5

describe "#morse_encode" do
  it "should do a simple letter" do
    morse_encode("q").should == "--.-"
  end

  it "should handle a small word" do
    morse_encode("cat").should == "-.-. .- -"
  end

  it "should handle a phrase" do
    morse_encode("cat in hat").should == "-.-. .- -  .. -.  .... .- -"
  end
end
```

My solution is

```
MORSE_CODE = {
  "a" => ".-",
  "b" => "-...",
  "c" => "-.-.",
  "d" => "-..",
  "e" => ".",
  "f" => "..-.",
  "g" => "--.",
  "h" => "....",
  "i" => "..",
  "j" => ".---",
  "k" => "-.-",
  "l" => ".-..",
  "m" => "--",
  "n" => "-.",
  "o" => "---",
  "p" => ".--.",
  "q" => "--.-",
  "r" => ".-.",
  "s" => "...",
  "t" => "-",
  "u" => "..-",
  "v" => "...-",
  "w" => ".--",
  "x" => "-..-",
  "y" => "-.--",
  "z" => "--.."
}

def morse_encode(str)
  arrayer = str.split(" ")
  combiner = arrayer.map {|word| morse_encode_word(word) }
  combiner.join("  ")
end

def morse_encode_word(word)
    letters = word.split("")

  array = letters.map {|x| MORSE_CODE[x]}

  array.join(" ")
end

morse_encode("cat in hat")
morse_encode_word("cat in hat")
```

Why are morse_encode and morse_encode_word returning the exact same output?

The way I created it, I would think there would be spacing differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass a phrase into `morse_encode_word`, it splits it by letters (that is, `'t i'` becomes `['t', ' ', 'i']`. Next, you map this array to `['-', nil, '..']` (because `MORSE_CODE[' '] == nil`).

And then you join it with space, `'-' + ' ' + '' + ' ' + '..'` (because `nil.to_s == ''`). So you get string with two spaces inside, `'-  ..'`.

Comment: What do you think is the best way to fix my solution so that there is only 1 space in between words for morse_encode_word? because the main function should be morse_encode, I don't want morse_encode_word to work for it too.

Comment: @JamieS what exact output you are looking for? please tell,then we might give better solution.

Comment: I want there to be 2 spaces between words and 1 space between letters for morse_encode. morse_encode_word should be different and shouldnt be able to do a complete string correctly, I want it to just have one space between every letter. I cant think of a way of doing this besides adding a delete or next function for the parameters of morse_encode_word (to delete the spaces)

Comment: You can modify last line to `array.compact.join(" ")`

Answer (score 2):

When you do morse_encode_word you are not getting rid of spaces... So it will split your words, but keep the space.

In morse_encode you get rid of the space (because of split), but you add it back in when you do the join. So it ends up being the same as morse_encode_word.

I would guess that what you want is no extra spaces in morse_encode_word. Just do a check to make sure x is not a space before you map it in morse_encode_word.

Try to use reject:

```
def morse_encode_word(word)
  letters = word.split("")

  array = letters.reject{|x| x == " "}.map{|x| MORSE_CODE[x]}

  array.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: I want there to be 2 spaces between words and 1 space between letters for morse_encode. morse_encode_word should be different and shouldnt be able to do a complete string correctly, I want it to just have one space between every letter. I cant think of a way of doing this besides adding a delete or next function for the parameters of morse_encode_word (to delete the spaces). Is there another way of doing this without deleting or nexting?